# How do I prevent Jenkins from aborting builds if later builds "overtake"?

Tags: jenkins

When starting a set of builds in fast succession, Jenkins interrupts the earlier builds and continues only the latest. **Can I switch this feature off, i.e. enforce that every build is built to the full?**

[image]

*Sample screenshot. Builds #2287, #2288, and #2289 started in rapid succession. Jenkins aborted the first two and continued only the latest #2289.*

In our larger team, this has repeatedly caused confusion if the latest build fails. First, it is no longer possible to determine exactly which of the three or four builds introduced the problem. Second, if the earlier builds contained important fixes, they were never delivered only because some later, less important build, overruled them.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is tbe [Random String Parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/random-string-parameter/)

Adds a new parameter type called Random String Parameter which inserts a random string that prevents Jenkins from merging multiple job runs into one.

Comment: Not sure. I don't really see Jenkins "merging" things. It's more that the individual builds are aborted prematurely. Added a screenshot to make clearer what I mean. Would the plug-in you recommend fix this? Could you elaborate a little how it works, or point somewhere that does explain it?

Comment: It does not merge builds, it just forces every build to run to completion. The introduction of the random parameter make each I stance unique so Jenkins run s every one. It's only when you run the same job w/no or same parameters that it would abort existing and start next.

Comment: Also not clear on "they were never delivered only because some later build overruled them". Jenkins will run the latest commit of code. It would be a dev overwriting by committing changes. You will see the aggregate changes reflwcted in the build, unless you're doing something atypical in your approach.

Comment: Yes, you see the aggregate builds, but only much later, after the completely unrelated later, failing build has been moved out of the way, and another build has passed all stages.

Comment: Take a copy of the job, add the plugin and try. It's enabled per job.